# How to claim free space generated by deleting docker images in Mac

Tags: docker

I started using docker images and suddenly i realized lack of space. It took me a while to know that space is being consumed by docker images. So I deleted all the running containers and unnecessary images only to realize that the result of `df -h` is still the same. I could see `~/.docker/machine/machines/default/disk.vmdk` still occupying 25GB of space (no change). How can I reclaim the freed space occupied by virtual box image. I am using Mac Yosemite and docker tool (not `boot2docker`)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to remove the machine. Use

```
docker-machine rm default
```

(`default` is the name of the default docker-machine)

Beware that you will delete all the images in this way.

There might be ways to compact disk image size (look at this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/529149/how-to-compact-virtualboxs-vdi-file-size)), but I don't think it worth the hassle. Instead recreate it with a smaller disk size.

Just to be clear, removing the containers and images only save space inside the VM. You can anyway in the future run into trouble because old unused images and container volumes might fill your VM disk. There are actions to be taken to keep it under control, the first of all is always removing containers with the `-v` flag.

Comment: You saved me man. Recreating only required docker images is much simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

Resizing Boot2Docker Disk Volumes
http://learningdocker.com/resizing-boot2docker-disk-volumes/

> As documented on Docker’s official website, the solution is to resize
>   the disk volume using a hard drive partitioning tool called Gnome
>   Partition Editor (GParted). Available as a free bootable ISO, GParted
>   is a free partition manager that enables users to resize, copy, and
>   move partitions without data loss. The version of GParted used in this
>   tutorial is gparted-live-0.20.0-2-i486.iso.

1) Stop the Boot2Docker virtual machine.

```
Host% boot2docker stop
```

2) The Boot2Docker package installer ships with a VMDK volume, which VirtualBox’s native tools cannot resize. In order to resize the Boot2Docker disk volume, first clone the VDI volume from the default VMDK volume.

```
Host% vboxmanage clonehd /full/path/to/boot2docker-vm.vmdk /full/path/to/boot2docker-vm.vdi --format VDI --variant Standard

# For Boot2Docker installations using the default settings, "/full/path/to/"
# is typically "~/VirtualBox\ VMs/boot2docker-vm/".  This tutorial will assume
# "/full/path/to/" to be "~/VirtualBox\ VMs/boot2docker-vm/".

Host% vboxmanage clonehd ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/boot2docker-vm/boot2docker-vm.vmdk ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/boot2docker-vm/boot2docker-vm.vdi --format VDI --variant Standard
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Clone hard disk created in format 'VDI'. UUID: f37d6330-c6f3-4a2d-914b-f61c3249ca0b
```

3) Resize the newly cloned VDI volume to the desired capacity. We recommend at least 64GB.

```
Host% vboxmanage modifyhd ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/boot2docker-vm/boot2docker-vm.vdi --resize <size in MB>
```